# Copy constructor for a generic doubly-linked list

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
class list
{
public:
    //stuff
    list(const list &cctorList); //cctor
private:
    struct node
    {
       node *next;
       node *previous;
       T *info;
    }

    node *firstNode; //pointer to the first node (NULL if none)
    node *lastNode; //pointer to the last node (NULL if none)
}
```

I'm now trying to define `list(const list &cctorList); //cctor` but I'm running into trouble.

Here's what I have so far:

```
template <class T>
list<T>::list(const list &cctorList)
{
    node *another = new node;
    firstNode = another;
    another->previous = NULL;
    another->info = new T(*(cctorList->info));

    // ...
}
```

Is everything up to this point correct?  Is there a way for me to recursively assign `another->next`?  Also, is there an easier way to accomplish this using iterators?

Comment: Any reason to avoid `std::list`?

Comment: See also [Should I use C style in C++](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/174997/should-i-use-c-style-in-c) on Programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should be using `std::list`. In fact, you should be using `std::vector`, because it is faster for most practical purposes (list is only faster if the objects are really large or really expensive to construct) and you don't need random access.
2. `new T(*(cctorList->info));` won't compile, because `cctorList` (`list&`) does not have `operator->` and it does not have `info` member either.
3. The copy constructor is best implemented in terms of the other, more primitive operations like `push_back` and iteration. So first do those and than the copy constructor becomes:

   ```
   template <class T>
   list<T>::list(const list &cctorList)
   {
       std::copy(begin(cctorList), end(cctorList), std::back_inserter(this));
   }
   ```

   In fact I'd just template that constructor:

   ```
   template <class T, class Collection> list(const Collection &cctorList)
   ```

   (body remains the same). That works as copy constructor, but also allows copying from any other collection of any type that can be implicitly converted to T.
4. The actual data should be held by *value*. I.e. the `node` should be defined as

   ```
   struct node
   {
       node *next;
       node *previous;
       T info;
   }
   ```

   you are copying the value anyway, so you don't need to do two separate allocations for `node` and `T` when one will do.

---

Edit: You say you want to learn concepts. But the most important concept of modern C++ is composition of algorithms. Their definitions are often trivial. Basic implementation of `std::copy` is just:

```
template <typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator copy(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end, OutputIterator out) {
    for(;begin != end; ++out, ++begin) *out = *begin;
}
```

Now this does not appear to allocate anything. The trick lies in the `back_insertion_iterator`. Insertion iterator is a trick to make this work without preallocating the sequences. It defines `operator*` using `push_back` on the underlying collection and ignores `operator++`. That satisfies "output iterator" concept, because it only guarantees to work when these two calls are strictly interleaved and makes algorithms work on many things from plain old arrays to output streams.

The other part is that while the trivial definitions are correct, they are not the actual definitions used in the library. The actual definitions in the library are optimized. E.g. usually `std::copy` will check whether the input iterators know their distance and if the output is insert operator to sequence with `reserve` operation and call it to avoid some allocations. Those are optimizations and depend on implementation details of the standard library.

You can go and write down the basic implementations of things from standard library and test they work the same if you want to understand them. But you should follow the way standard library defines things by building them up from simple helper bits like `std::copy`, `std::swap`, insertion iterator adapters and such. If you look in the standard library, most functions there are one-liners!

Edit2: Also with all the genericity the standard library provides, there are still bits criticized for not being generic enough. E.g. [GotW #84: Monoliths "Unstrung"](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm) discusses which methods of `std::string` could be converted to generic algorithms.

Comment: What about new T(*(cctorList->first.info));?

Comment: Also, how can I define this outside of list?

Comment: @BobJohn: `new T(*(cctorList->first.info))` is still wrong. It would have to be `new T(cctorList.first->info)`, but that doesn't really matter. It should be `push_back(begin(cctorList))` done from within that `std::copy`.

Comment: @BobJohn: _what_ do you want to define outside of `list`?

Comment: I don't want to use std::copy nor std::back_inserter.

Comment: @BobJohn: _why_ don't you want to use them? This is the standard way of doing things in modern C++.

Comment: I feel that the appropriate definitions will help me understand the concepts more intuitively.

Comment: Then implement the copy and the back_inserter yourself. In general, build your "bigger" steps (i.e. the copy ctor) in terms of smaller steps (i.e. iterating through the original and `push_back`). Don't try to implement the whole copy construction "by hand", that will only create a big unmaintainable mess.